# Code compiles in CLion but not in Command Prompt

Tags: c++, gcc, namespaces, command-prompt, clion

I am trying to a C++ library and need (want) to use nested namespaces in order to increase readability of the code. However, I am running into a problem when trying to compile my code in the Windows Command Prompt with `g++ main.c`.

The code below is an example of what I will have -- a nested namespace and then some functions or classes:

```cpp
namespace gpc::warning {
    void raiseError() {
        std::cout << "Error...\n";
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

The code below is an example for my `main.c` file:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Warning/raise.hpp"

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    gpc::warning::raiseError();

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this simple probram in CLion, it compiles and runs perfectly, however when I run the code in the Windows 10 Command Prompt, I get the following error telling me something about the namespaces:

```
In file included from main.cpp:2:0:
Warning/raise.hpp:10:14: error: expected '{' before '::' token
 namespace gpc::warning {
              ^
Warning/raise.hpp:10:16: error: 'warning' in namespace '::' does not name a type
 namespace gpc::warning {
                ^
main.cpp: In function 'int gpc::main()':
main.cpp:9:10: error: 'gpc::warning' has not been declared
     gpc::warning::raiseError();
          ^
main.cpp: At global scope:
main.cpp:12:1: error: expected '}' at end of input
 }
 ^
```

I was wondering what I am doing wrong and how I can fix this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: have you checked whether the syntax you use for defining the nested namespace is compatible with your compiler version? c.f.: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace

Comment: Im using C++ 20 so I think the ```n1::n2``` syntax works...

Comment: Which g++ version are you using?? Share the output of following command: `g++ --version`.

Comment: @Pencilcaseman I don't think that C++20 is supported by any of the g++ compilers available on Windows.

Comment: Apparently im using g++ version 4.9.2 which I think is probably the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try updating your `g++` version to `6.1.0` or higher.

The code doesn't compiles on `g++ v5.5.0` even with `-std=gnu++17` flag. You can check that [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/bxK6dCO7yHjOxbs7). (Reason: Nested namespaces weren't supported by the *compiler* then.)

The code shall compile with compiler defaults (without any flags) on `g++ v6.1.0` or higher. You can check this [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/qqVfhzN543kZKSEn).

You can check your compiler version by running: `g++ --version` on `cmd`.

Pro Tip: Locate your CLion's compiler and if it is `g++` then add that one to path. (No need of wasting internet data on updating the old `g++` compiler!)

Comment: I have found the ```c++.exe``` file and added the directory to PATH, but the version remains the same unless I am in the same directory as ```c++.exe```...

Comment: @Pencilcaseman that's probably because on top of the c++.exe you are having the old g++. Put `c++.exe` on the top of your `PATH` variable. Order matters in the list of PATH variable.